# TP-Link EAP670 AP and TL-SG1210MPE Switch: Guest network VLAN configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vlan

I'm trying to set up a simple guest wifi network on a separate VLAN from my main network.

**Physical connections:**

- My EAP670 access point is connected to port 1 on the network switch.
- Port 10 on the network switch is connected to my router.

**WiFi networks**

- SSID "T" is my private network on VLAN1
- SSID "B" is my guest network on VLAN2

With everything configured, I can only access the internet on SSID "T" (VLAN1). The guest SSID "B" cannot retrieve an IP address. Both VLANs have port 10 as untagged so they should be able to reach the router equally...

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for your help.

Switch setup:

[image: Switch VLAN setup]

[image: Switch PVID setup]

AP setup:

[image: AP setup]

Answer (score 0):

> Both VLANs have port 10 as untagged so they should be able to reach the router equally...

That's actually a problem. The tags are literally what carries VLAN IDs from one device to another, i.e. they're how the AP knows *which* VLAN each packet belongs to. ("Tagged/untagged" primarily works in the opposite direction – it tells the switch whether to add/retain or to remove tags for packets *leaving* the port, i.e. from the switch to AP.) Without VLAN tags, the AP has no choice but to assume the same VLAN for everything.

So when your 'SSID B' devices send out a DHCP request to the router, they can't get a reply because the AP didn't see a VLAN tag and assumed VLAN 1, forwarding the reply to 'SSID A' instead.

In other words, if the packets inbound to the AP are untagged, the AP does not know whether they correspond to VLAN ID 1 or 2, and assumes the same default (usually something like "VLAN 1" or "VLAN 0" meaning "no VLAN") for *all* packets.

Whenever you have multiple VLANs on a switch port, **all of them** (except one, usually) must be "tagged" on that port – there are *very few* situations when having more than one untagged VLAN per port makes sense.

Comment: `if the packets inbound to the AP are untagged, the AP does not know whether they correspond to VLAN ID 1 or 2` The packets to the AP are tagged though. The AP is connected to port 1 and both VLAN1 and VLAN2 has port 1 tagged. Port 10 to the router is untagged. Sorry, unless you accidentally mixed port 1 and port 10's devices, I'm having a hard time parsing your comment.

Comment: I did mix them up, yes... but that still means you have the exact same problem, just with the router instead. If the router receives both VLANs untagged, then it also won't know which of its VLAN interfaces each packet belongs to. Or if it expects untagged packets (no VLAN interfaces), then it won't tag outgoing packets either, making the switch internally mark everything as VLAN 1. What I said about having multiple untagged VLANs per port still applies.